# Progresively select sorted mongodb documents

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose

#### Context:

My code is in JavaScript (mongoose)

I have a database with a lot of users, I want to create a leaderboard based on their scores.
I plan to show 10 users at a time with arrows to navigate and show the next 10 users.

#### Ideas:

Is it possible to make a query and progressively get the users, like an iterator that fetches as I go?

Or have the limit:

```js
await Users.find({})
        .sort({ score: -1 })
        .limit(10);
```

And rerun the query to get the next 10 users

Finally, I could just get the documents one at a time, but  I don't really know how would I do this.

*Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.*

Comment: Why not? Just make sure the score field is indexed as it is used for the `$sort` and you should add skip before limit to do the page navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Skip and Limit for page navigation. i.e., pagination

```
const page = req.query.page * 1 || 1;
const limit = req.query.limit * 1 || 10;
const skip = (page - 1) * limit;
```

Then in the Query,

```
await User.find({})
          .sort({ score: -1 })
          .skip(skip).limit(limit);
```

Then in your Query

```
{{URL}}/User?page=1&limit=10
```

Comment: Thanks, `skip` is exactly what I wanted.